# Using gsubfn to replace many instances within a string

Tags: r, regex, gsubfn

I wrote a function that transforms a string representing a number (magrittr loaded in my system):

```
adjust_perc_format <- function(x, n=3){
  gsub(",", ".", x, perl = T) %>% as.numeric() %>% format(nsmall=n, decimal.mark = ",")
}
```

So that:

```
adjust_perc_format("2,5", 3) 
[1] "2,500"
```

The goal is to transform the ocurrences defined by a regex within a string (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/nFcwpl/1/)). For this purpose I tried gsubfn:

```
str <- "20MG/ML (2,5%)+0,5%"
gsubfn("[\\d,]+(?=%)", function(x) adjust_perc_format(x, n=3),str)
```

The expected result is `"20MG/ML (2,500%)+0,500%"`. Instead, I got the same input string (`"20MG/ML (2,5%)+0,5%"`).

I also tried to set the engine as below, no success:

```
options(gsubfn.engine = "R")
```

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `gsubfn` to use the whole match by passing the `backref=0` argument:

```r
gsubfn("[\\d,]+(?=%)", function(x) adjust_perc_format(x, n=3),str, backref=0)
```

R test:

```r
> library(gsubfn)
> str <- "20MG/ML (2,5%)+0,5%"
> gsubfn("[\\d,]+(?=%)", function(x) adjust_perc_format(x, n=3),str, backref=0)
[1] "20MG/ML (2,500%)+0,500%"
```

In case you want to make your pattern more reliable, you may use

```r
gsubfn("\\d+(?:,\\d+)*(?=%)", function(x) adjust_perc_format(x, n=3),str, backref=0)
```

which will match one or more digits followed with zero or more occurrences of a comma and one or more digits (followed with `%` that is not consumed as it is in a positive lookahead).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the robustness sugestion.